# How can I read from continuously updated file in Perl?

Tags: perl

Greetings, I want to read through a file, go to sleep and then check if new records were written to the file. If yes I want to process the records, if no go back to sleep and check again later (in a forever loop).

I thought I could do something like this but after it reads the file the first time through the while, it never seems to pick up the new records added to the file.

```
open (LOG, "<log_file") or die ("could not open log_file");

for (;  ;)   
{  
  print "Record Number == $.\n";   

  while ($text=<LOG>)     
  {                       
    chomp ($text);
    print "$text\n";
  }
  sleep (60);

}

close (LOG);
```

After reading the file originally the above script just keeps printing the record number of the last record in the file. 
I saw somethng about a TailFile package available but it appears I don't have it and it would be difficult to get loaded at this time. I am hoping for a vanilla perl solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

[File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Tail) is your friend.

Answer (score 9):

That's because your while loop will terminate when the filehandle returns EOF. You'll need to clear the EOF flag before reading.

Use seek, after the while loop and the sleep.

```
seek(LOG, 0, 1);
```

That literally says: move zero bytes from current position. It won't advance in the file, but does clear the EOF condition for the next read.

You can also use the IO::Handle module and call clearerr();

```
use IO::Handle;
# ...
LOG->clearerr();
```

Lastly, if you're willing to use a tie'd filehandle, there's a File::Tail module on CPAN you can try.

Answer (score 4):

This is covered by the Perl FAQ.  See [perldoc -q tail](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-do-I-do-a-%27tail--f%27-in-perl%3f) for the full entry.  If you are willing to install a [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) module, you should consider [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Tail/Tail.pm).

Answer (score 0):

@jmanning2k, Do you happen to have a link for handling this? The perl cookbook has the following, which seems very weak ...

```
for (;;) {
     while () { .... }
     sleep $SOMETIME;
     seek(FH, 0, 1);
 }
```

or the IO::Handle module's clearerr method:

```
use IO::Seekable;
for (;;) {
     while () { .... }
     sleep $SOMETIME;
     FH->clearerr();
 }
```