# PHP: reading a remote file that's being updated by an XML API

Tags: php, ajax, file-io, proxy

I am accessing an XML API (flight search comparison) via a PHP Proxy [like here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.de/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html).

The API always has a full file for download. The first version states there are 0 results, then after calling it a few times the first results pop up.

API documentation says:

> the result method will always give you the current state of the
>   searchresult. You may call it multiple times (maybe with ajax calls)

My problem is, I don't know when it's done, i.e. when all results are delivered.

I tried this:

1. read till `feof`, then reset the file position indicator via `fseek()` and wait a little [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425223/how-do-i-read-a-file-which-is-constantly-updating) but that doesn't work, as the stream is not supporting `fseek()`.
2. waiting *a few* seconds and then displaying the results, but that doesn't work well as the API sometimes needs very long (and I am not getting everything)
3. read till `feof`, then using `ftell()` to see whether new stuff has been written to the file, but I am lacking the possibility to do something afterwards ...

   ```
   $handle = fopen($flights_url, "r");
   if ($handle) {
       while (!feof($handle)) {
           $buffer = fgets($handle);
           echo $buffer;
       }
       fclose($handle);
   }
   ```

I am out of ideas now. How should this be done in a nice way?

-T

**Edit**: changed formatting and added some code

Comment: XML API like you're making an http request? Then you're being sent a snapshot of the file, not a stream right? What does your `fopen` or equivalent call look like?

Comment: It very much depends on the API you are using. There is no universal way to accomplish what you are asking.

Comment: @MikeB: added some code.

Comment: @lanzz: any suggestion then for this specific case?

Comment: You should read the API's docs and figure out how they signal the end of the processing.

Comment: @lanzz: I've read the docs, it's not much there generally and nothing regarding the "end of processing". That's why I am asking about a general way ...

Comment: No, there is no general way to test if any non-specified service's API will never ever change its response for a given request again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I contacted one of the API's developers.

He told me, that they don't send a ready-signal, because they also don't know, when the response is finished. This is because they work with so many other APIs (it's a comparison API, after all).

**The advice/solution** he gave me, and which they use, is to poll a few times, with a few seconds delay between each poll, and then just take what's there and leave the rest.

Seems rather pragmatic than elegant to me, but that's how they do it :-) Thanks to all who tried to give input!