# How to display a row of a file which is continuously updating on a server in Perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to display the updates of a file which is continuously updating. This file is accessed from a server, every time there is an update in the file it has to be printed. This is the code I have managed to build until now:

```
open(FH,'<','log_file.txt') or die $!;  # open file
for (;;) {
    while (my $row = <FH>) {
    chomp $row;
    print "$row\n";
    }
    sleep 1;
    seek FH, 0, 1;
}
```

The code reads the file, prints all existing rows and stays in the loop. Unfortunately, the code does not print the newly added rows. Any help on my issue?

Comment: [You're doing it right](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1425292/168657). Are you sure the file is being updated? Try displaying `-s "log_file.txt"` after you seek. Maybe the process that updates the file is buffering its output.

Comment: do you know a way of accessing the row and performing some actions with the data in the row?

Comment: are existing rows updated or is the only change new rows added at the end?

Comment: I geuess closing the file before the sleep and reopening it before the while would solve the problem. The file might not have been updated but rewritten completely.

Comment: Existing rows are not updated, the only update is adding new rows that I am trying to access and perform actions with them.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel; use [File::Tail](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Tail).

```
use File::Tail qw( );

my $tail = File::Tail->new('log_file.txt');
while (defined( my $line = $file->read() )) {
  print($line);
}
```

Unlike yours, its won't return partial lines, it detects log file rotations, etc.